# Golang & AWS: Deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I setup a golang web server and used the sample web application that they provided. After the deployment I went to the URL of the webserver and it worked.

I downloaded the sample application zip, unzipped it, rezipped it and upload the app and the deployment did not work.

However if I reuploaded the original sample zip it WOULD work. Based on this it appears something is wrong with how I'm zipping the source code. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is you might be missing any dotfiles/dirs (.ebextensions for example is a standard dot directory). I have not deployed golang app on eb before and this is just my guess. Event/error logs would have helped for us to give more information.

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, I was zipping the folder instead of the contents of the folder. After zipping the contents of the folder, it worked for me.